Use css whitespace in pre code syntaxhighlight version 11
According to official documentation, syntaxhightlight version 11 remove useBR configuration.
It recommend to use plugin or simply css white-space:pre
I can do it with plugin like this.


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hightlight With Plugin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <pre><code>&lt;div class="code"&gt;<br />&lt;script&gt;<br />console.log("Hello, World!");<br />&lt;/script&gt;<br />&lt;/div&gt;</code></pre>

  <script>
    //https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2559
    const brPlugin = {
      "before:highlightBlock": ({
        block
      }) => {
        block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/<br[ /]*>/g, '\n');
      },
      "after:highlightBlock": ({
        result
      }) => {
        result.value = result.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
      }
    };

    // how to use it
    hljs.addPlugin(brPlugin);

    hljs.highlightAll();
  </script>
</body>

</html>



How to do it with simply css white-space:pre ?
